# How to display particular name post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' );
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    echo '<p>' . $post_type. '</p>';
}
```

This is the output:

> post
>
> page
>
> attachment
>
> revision
>
> nav_menu_item
>
> produks

I need 'produces' not display.

Comment: If you want only WP default post types then you can use `_builtin` parameter in argument. Will this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you are after, but to NOT display produks in your output you could echo when $post_type does not match that string.

```
$post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' );
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    if($post_type != 'produks'){
        echo '<p>' . $post_type. '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way using your example is to do this using a `!in_array()` check:

```
$exclude_post_types = array('produks');
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    if (!in_array($post_type, $exclude_post_types)) {
        echo '<p>' . $post_type. '</p>';
    }
}
```

The benefit of having the `$exclude_post_types` array is you can add to that array without having to create another `!=` conditional check.

But there must be a better way to do that in the WordPress query without having to fetch all post types and then run the PHP logic I have in place. But at least this does give you the desired results.